# Pipe vs redirect into process

Tags: bash

Looking for some **bash-expert** explanation. What is the exact difference between of the next

```
command1 | command2
```

e.g. classic pipe where the stdout of command1 is redirected to the stdin of command2, e.g.

- bash forks itself two times
- changes the file descriptors
- exec the comman1 and command2

and

```
command1 > >(command2)
```

where the result (and the bash actions) are the same...

At least i got the same from the

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I% echo =%=
```

and

```
find . -print0 > >(xargs -0 -n1 -I% echo =%=)
```

Is the `> >(command)` only the longer way saying `|`? Or not, and I missed something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To implement

```
command1 | command2
```

the shell creates a pipe in the parent process and attaches one end of it to the output (fd 1; it uses dup or dup2) of command1, and the other end to the input (fd 0) of command2.

To implement

```
command1 > >(command 2)
```

, the shell creates a FIFO.  It attaches the command2's stdin to the FIFO (with open using the O_WRONLY flag, usually) and it passes the name of the FIFO as a positional argument to command1.  You can easily see this by using `echo >(true)`.

If you use the

```
> >(foo)
```

these forms are indeed very similar.   However, the process subsititution mechanism is more powerful.  For example you get do this kind of thing:

```
diff -u  <(curl 'http://www.a.example.com/')  <(curl 'http://www.b.example.com/')
```

You can't do that with pipes - you can't have two standard inputs.

Answer (score 5):

At least part of a difference is discussed in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006148/looking-for-explanation-of-shell-redirection-interleaving-behaviour).

An additional difference is control over which processes run in sub-shells:

```
$ declare -p f b
-bash: declare: f: not found
-bash: declare: b: not found
$ { f=foo; true; } | { b=bar; true; }
$ declare -p f b
-bash: declare: f: not found
-bash: declare: b: not found
$ { f=foo; true; } > >( { b=bar; true; })
$ declare -p f b
declare -- f="foo"
-bash: declare: b: not found
```